# What are mse matrices obtained from dlmSvd2var function (the dlm package) in R?

Tags: r, kalman-filter

I've read the documentation and tried looking it up online, but am unable to find anything meaningful. What do these matrices mean?

Additionally, is there any way to calculate the MSE for the whole prediction from these matrices?